# error in mysql query for join and picking the latest date record

Tags: mysql, sql-update

```
UPDATE Fact_List sfl, Respondents_Dim rd SET sfl.Zip = rd.Zip where sfl.Panel_Id=rd.Panel_Id HAVING MAX(rd.Valid_From)

respondents_dim` (
  `Respondents_Key` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Panel_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `First_Name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Last_Name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Specialty` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Dataset` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sex` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Zip` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Valid_From` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Valid_To` date DEFAULT NULL)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fact_list` (
  `Panel_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Project_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Zip` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Employee_Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Created_Date` date DEFAULT NULL
)
```

The first update command is to update fact_list table with Zip from respondents_dim where both join using panel_id but there might be multiple records with that id and the latest valid_from date should be considered.

I tried to execute it but it is giving following error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING MAX(rd.Valid_From)' at line 1

Is there anything wrong in the query?

Answer (score 0):

Try with left join :-

**Edited**: Remove alias and put the name of tables.

**Edited 2** : Try once.

```
    UPDATE Fact_List  left join Respondents_Dim  on Fact_List.Panel_Id=Respondents_Dim.Panel_Id SET Fact_List.Zip = Respondents_Dim.Zip 
where Respondents_Dim.Valid_From in (select  MAX(Respondents_Dim.Valid_From) from Respondents_Dim)
```

Comment: same error                                                        #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING MAX(rd.Valid_From)' at line 1

Comment: Now check @user1597811. If its working fine then accept as answered/solved.

Comment: Hi Lucia, Thanks for the reply. I tried it but still the same error mentioned above.

Comment: Yes the one you edited 19 mins ago. I cross checked it again. I guess there is some problem with having there bcoz the error message pointing it! Any Idea?

Comment: Another more way to do it... EDITED

Comment: It is executing but the logic changed entirely. Instead of taking records that match panel_id's and then compare resulted records valid_from date for max. it is taking entire dates from the table and getting max of it

Comment: The problem is in having clause, you require to replace it with another condition. Have you tried anything other ?

Comment: Got no Idea what else to use as I'm new to this Im exploring...can u suggest any?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE fact_list fl
LEFT JOIN respondents_dim rd
ON rd.Panel_Id = fl.Panel_Id
SET fl. Zip = rd.Zip
WHERE rd.Valid_From = (SELECT MAX(Valid_From) 
                       FROM respondents_dim rd2
                       WHERE rd2.Panel_Id = rd.Panel_Id)
```

or to avoid the correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE fact_list fl
INNER JOIN respondents_dim rd
ON rd.Panel_Id = fl.Panel_Id
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT Panel_Id, MAX(Valid_From) AS max_Valid_From
    FROM respondents_dim 
    GROUP BY Panel_Id) AS rd2
ON rd.Panel_Id = rd2.Panel_Id 
AND rd.Valid_From = rd2.max_Valid_From
SET fl.Zip = rd.Zip
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is somehow running for ages and not updating anything?

Comment: @user1597811 Try the not correlated query, and if it it still slow, make sure you have indexes on Panel_ID and Valid_From.